# Событие при переключении тавоб внутри балуна яндекс карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Какое событие срабатывает, когда переключаешь табы внутри балуна?
мне при переключении таба нужно отправить аякс запрос
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В общем я сделал так

```
$this.map.geoObjects.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
                document.querySelectorAll('.ymaps-2-1-79-b-cluster-tabs__menu-item').forEach(function (tab){
                    tab.addEventListener('click', function (){
                        setTimeout(function (){
                            var btn = document.querySelector('.js-btn');
                            $this.fetchDeliverytPriceHandler(btn.dataset.id);
                        }, 300);
                    });
                });
            });
```

Решение конечно корявенькое, но хотя бы работает
Может кто-то предложит более элегантное решение?